# Plotly fill area with condition R

Tags: r, colors, conditional-statements, plotly, fill

I have the following code:

```
library(plotly)
df = data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04")),
                v1=c(2,4,5,6),
                v2=c(1,2,7,2))
fig <- plot_ly(data=df, x = ~Date)
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~v1,
                         type = 'scatter',
                         mode = 'lines',
                         name = 'v1') 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~v2,
                         type = 'scatter',
                         mode = 'lines',
                         fill = 'tonexty',
                         fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)',
                         name = 'v2') 
fig <- fig %>% layout(xaxis = list(title="Date"))
fig
```

[image]

My goal is to fill the area with a color based on a condition (**without using ggplot**):

- If v1 > v2, the filled area is red.
- If v2 > v1, the filled area is blue.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

My solution is kind of ugly, but it worked (at least for two lines). I don't see how you could do it in `plotly` without explicitly finding out the points where the lines intersect and changing the dataframe to include these points.

```
library(plotly)
df = data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04")),
                v1=c(2,4,5,6),
                v2=c(1,2,7,2))

# get "origin" of x axis
origin.x <- min(df$Date)

df.aux <- df %>% 
  # compute intercept and slope parameters of line segments
  dplyr::mutate(slope.v1=(lead(v1)-v1)/as.integer(lead(Date)-Date),
                intercept.v1=v1-slope.v1*as.integer(Date-origin.x),
                slope.v2=(lead(v2)-v2)/as.integer(lead(Date)-Date),
                intercept.v2=v2-slope.v2*as.integer(Date-origin.x)) %>%
  # check where line segments in the same x interval intersect
  dplyr::mutate(cross.x=(intercept.v1 - intercept.v2)/(slope.v2 - slope.v1)) %>%
  # check if intersection happens in the "current" x interval
  dplyr::mutate(cross.in.step=cross.x > as.integer(Date-origin.x) & cross.x < as.integer(lead(Date)-origin.x)) %>%
  # keep only lines that are intersecting
  dplyr::filter(cross.in.step) %>%
  # calculate y values of intersections
  dplyr::mutate(cross.y=intercept.v1 + slope.v1 * cross.x) %>%
  # convert intersection in x axis to date
  dplyr::mutate(Date=origin.x + lubridate::seconds(as.integer(cross.x*24*3600)),
                v1=cross.y,
                v2=cross.y) %>%
  # keep only relevant columns
  dplyr::select(Date, v1, v2)

# add intersection points to original dataframe
df.2 <- bind_rows(df, df.aux) %>% dplyr::arrange(Date) %>%
  # compute lower bound line and upper bound line
  dplyr::mutate(Date=Date,
                inf.y=pmin(v1, v2),
                sup.y=pmax(v1, v2))

df.2
#                 Date       v1       v2    inf.y    sup.y
#1 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2.000000 1.000000 1.000000 2.000000
#2 2020-01-02 00:00:00 4.000000 2.000000 2.000000 4.000000
#3 2020-01-02 12:00:00 4.500000 4.500000 4.500000 4.500000
#4 2020-01-03 00:00:00 5.000000 7.000000 5.000000 7.000000
#5 2020-01-03 08:00:00 5.333333 5.333333 5.333333 5.333333
#6 2020-01-04 00:00:00 6.000000 2.000000 2.000000 6.000000

# add traces in this order
fig <- plot_ly(df.2, x = ~Date) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~v1, type = 'scatter',mode = 'lines',name = 'v1')  %>%
  # add invisible line with fill area from lower bound to v1
  add_trace(y = ~inf.y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', name = 'v1>v2',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(100,0,0,0.2)', showlegend=F)  %>%
  add_trace(y = ~v2, type = 'scatter',mode = 'lines',name = 'v2')  %>%
  # add invisible line with fill area from lower bound to v2
  add_trace(y = ~inf.y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', name = 'v1<v2',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,0,100,0.2)', showlegend=F)
```

[image]